# on click button refresh a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify

I am working on a shopify website. what I am trying to achieve is to, click on a button it should refresh a particular div only, without refreshing the whole page, my button class is a "button.nav-link.nav-cart.header__icon.header__icon--button.header__icon--cart"  and my div which I want to refresh is "cart-drawer-container"

```js
jQuery("button.nav-link.nav-cart.header__icon.header__icon--button.header__icon--cart").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   jQuery.get(jQuery(this).attr("href"), function(data) {
      jQuery(".header__icon--cart").html(data);
   });
});
```

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("button.nav-link.nav-cart.header__icon.header__icon--button.header__icon--cart").click(function(){
    $(".header__icon--cart").load(".cart-drawer-container");
  });
});
```

Comment: The code doesn't look bad,  are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: No error, but it refreshes the whole page

Comment: it shows the whole page in the div

Comment: You forgot `e.preventDefault()` in the second piece of code, so the default behaviour is to reload the whole page

Comment: can you please give me the full code, I am bit confused

Comment: Well you did write `e.preventDefault()` in the first piece of code. You only forgot it in the second one. As a consequence, on click the default behaviour happens, which is : reload the page. If you don't want that, you can block it with `e.preventDefault()`.